# Reading ZIP files using Spark or AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to read a compressed file which is uploaded on s3.

Functionality: When any file is uploaded on s3, a lambda is triggered which triggers a spark job.

Where should I read the file, in AWS Lambda or through Apache Spark? which one would be beneficial?
How should I read compressed files in spark?

Answer (score 0):

You ask multiple question. So I try to answer each of your question.

> Where do I need to read: through lambda or through spark, which one would be beneficial?

You can let s3 trigger lambda , and lambda trigger EMR spark.

Here are many example for you

- [How to execute spark submit on amazon EMR from Lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795776/how-to-execute-spark-submit-on-amazon-emr-from-lambda-function)
- [AWS Lambda — How to Automate Your Spark Jobs on AWS Elastic Map Reduce (EMR)](https://medium.com/@sdmandrell/aws-lambda-how-to-automate-your-spark-jobs-on-aws-elastic-map-reduce-emr-4fb71369ac48)
- [Orchestrate Apache Spark applications using AWS Step Functions and Apache Livy](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-apache-spark-applications-using-aws-step-functions-and-apache-livy/)

> How should I read compressed files in spark?

First, which kind of compressed file? Spark and Hadoop support following compressed type

```
name    | ext      | codec class
-------------------------------------------------------------
bzip2   | .bz2     | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec 
default | .deflate | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec 
deflate | .deflate | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec 
gzip    | .gz      | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec 
lz4     | .lz4     | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec 
snappy  | .snappy  | org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
```

If your compressed type is supported, you can read compressed files by following example code.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("s3://bucket/project/logfilexxxxx.*.gz")
```